# On the recent color change of flag/edit queue notification

Tags: feature-request, design

I noticed that the colors of the numbers indicating a non-empty flag review, or edit review, have been changed recently.

After a short rummaging through the meta.SO site, I found out that these was done to have a uniform coloring schema of the top bar across the network, which is fine on paper.

However the chosen colors are not fine. They ignore the part of the population which has troubles discerning certain colors in certain backgrounds. More to the point, the choice of dark color to the edit review queue is difficult to see, and this causes the number to be less apparent, and thus less notable, which I find counterproductive.

> Is it possible to restore the lighter colors, even if globally, and to make it easier to see that there are edits in the queue?

(I should also say that whatever color the flags counter is now, it looks remarkably similar to the previous color of the edits counter, which is also confusing, but that I can live with.)

Comment: If anyone wants, here's the meta.SO question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212372/top-bar-should-be-consistent-on-all-sites-but-its-not (For what it's worth, I'm not a big fan of the change either)

Comment: Also, it looks like they switched up the color scheme; blue for flags and orange for edits